# Regex Remove Images with style tag from Html

Tags: php, regex

I am new to Regex, however I decided it was the easiest route to what I needed to do.  Basically I have a string (in PHP) which contains a whole load of HTML code... I want to remove any  tags which have style=display:none...

so for example

`<img src="" style="display:none" />`

`<img src="" style="width:11px;display: none" >`

etc...

So far my Regex is:

`<img.*style=.*display.*:.*none;.* >`

But that seems to leave bits of html behind and also take the next element away when used in php with preg_replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like Michael pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772782/regex-remove-images-with-style-tag-from-html/2772854#2772854), you don't want to use Regex for this purpose. A Regex does not know what an element tag is. `<foo>` is as meaningful as `>foo<` unless you teach it the difference. Teaching the difference is incredibly tedious though.

DOM is so much more convenient:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<img src="" style="display:none" />
<IMG src="" style="width:11px;display: none" >
<img src="" style="width:11px" >
HTML;
```

The above is our (invalid) markup. We feed it to DOM like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$dom->normalizeDocument();
```

Now we query the DOM for all "IMG" elements containing a "style" attribute that contains the text "display". We could query for "display: none" in the XPath, but our input markup has occurences with no space inbetween:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//img[contains(@style, "display")]') as $node) {
    $style = str_replace(' ', '', $node->getAttribute('style'));
    if(strpos($style, 'display:none') !== FALSE) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

We iterate over the IMG nodes and remove all whitespace from their style attribute content. Then we check if it contains "display:none" and if so, remove the element from the DOM.

Now we only need to save our HTML:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

gives us:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><img src="" style="width:11px"></body></html>
```

Screw Regex!

---

Addendum: you might also be interested in [Parsing XML documents with CSS selectors](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/42/parsing-xml-documents-with-css-selectors)

Comment: thanks, didn't realize there was a dom parse built into php (although I should have guessed there is a function for everything else)... your suggestion has worked, even with unusual images...

Comment: Something to note with the above, after testing for some time it doesn't work if the 'display' is capital... use:
[contains(translate(@style, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), "display")] for the xpath instead

Comment: @Mark you could also use http://de.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php and use `strotolower` or `stripos`

Answer (score 4):

```
$html = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+style[^>]+none[^>]+>/", '', $html);
```

Comment: thanks works great... no idea how you came up with it but works!

Comment: this will match any IMG elements with any css attribute in style containing the word "none", including `border-style:none;`

Comment: Gordon: Yes, y're right. it's easy to modify:
$html = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+style[^>]display:\s*none[^>]+>/", '', $html);

Comment: `<img style="width:11px;" title="Use display:none to hide stuff" src="Dont-Parse-Html-With-Regex.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Because `<img>` doesn't allow any other elements inside it, this is possible; but in general, regexp is a thoroughly bad tool for parsing a recursively defined language like HTML.

Anyway, the problem you're probably hitting is that the closing > is being matched by one of the .* expressions, and there happens to be a later > on the line to match your explicit > .

If you replace all your .* by [^>]* that will prevent that. (They probably don't *all* need to be replaced, but you might as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is way too broad; `.*` means "match anything", so this would match:

```
<img src="foo.png" style="something">Some random displayed text : foo none; bar<br>
```

At the very least, you probably want to exclude closing brackets from your matches, so `[^>]*` instead of `.*`. You also might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), though, and look into using something that actually understands HTML, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version which works with all tags including ones with spaces between the inline style **display:none** or **display: none**. Plus it deletes the content inside the tags.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<[^>]+style[^>]+display:\s*none[^>]+>.*?>/', '', $html);
```

So I have tested it with the following and it works fine.

```
Only show<div style='display:none'>Delete inside content as well</div> this text.

Only show<span style='display: none'>Delete inside content as well</span> this text.

Only show<div style="display: none">Delete inside content as well</div> this text.

Only show<span style="display:none;">Delete inside content as well</span> this text.
```

Should now only output.

```
Only show this text.
```