# Remove IMG tag from String for a specific image with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a block of text that has a particular image that I want to strip out. The problem is that the  tag can be with different styles

for e.g

```
<img src="myimage.png" alt="" class=""/>
```

or

```
<img alt="" class="" src="myimage.png"/>
```

or

```
<img class="" alt ="" src="myimage.png"/>
```

Now how can I remove that particular image tag from my string using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Remove Images with style tag from Html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772782/regex-remove-images-with-style-tag-from-html)

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$str = 'Lorem <img alt="" class="" src="myimage.png"/> ipsum <img class="" alt="" src="myimage.png"/> dolor <img src="myimage.png"/> sit...';
echo preg_replace('!<img.*?src="myimage.png".*?/>!i', '', $str);
// output: "Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit..."
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

if you meant to extract attributes, try

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
```