# php use preg_replace remove div

Tags: php, preg-replace

I tried use `preg_replace` remove the div which `class="image content"`, I use some code below, but still remain two `</div>` after my `preg_replace`, need a help, thanks.

```
<style>
#contract{width:100%;height:100%;}
#content{width:1002px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;}
</style>
<div id="contract">
<div id="content">
<?php
$html = <<<EOT
<div style="float:left;" class="image content"><div style="float:left;"><div style="float:left;">
    <img alt="Se hai problemi nella visualizzazione dei caratteri, clicca qui." src="../../image/1001.jpg" >
</div></div></div>
<div class="content" style="float:left;"><i>some content here.</i></div>
EOT;
echo preg_replace('/<div(.*?)class="image content">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/','',$html);
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I need return: `<div class="content" style="float:left;"><i>some content here.</i></div>`

Comment: Wrap the extraneous `(</div>)+`, or use DOMDocument (or rather the less cumbersome phpQuery/querypath/fluentdom) since your regex usage seems clumsy. (You have a few more problems there.)

Comment: @mario, how to `Wrap the extraneous (</div>)+`? `preg_replace('/<div(.*?)class="image content">([\s\S]*?)(<\/div>)+/','',$html);` not work.

Comment: Most epic answer at stackoverflow to similar broblem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Remove Images with style tag from Html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772782/regex-remove-images-with-style-tag-from-html) shows how to do it with DOM. Doesnt matter if its for Images and Style tags because with DOM its the same for all elements and attributes. The abstract problem is removing element by attribute value

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not answer to this question, but don't use regular expressions for manipulating with DOM. There are specialized classes for that ([DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)), which are faster and will cause you less headache.

Comment: I want remove all the unwilling thing in a long long text, than use `preg_split` for cut each `div` into small peaces for a `mysql insert`. so I think it is more easier use `preg_replace` for my whole code. Thanks.